# XAML Label: binding text content when using text styles

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, binding

I had the following XAML:

```
<Label>
    <Underline Foreground="Blue">Foo</Underline>
</Label>
```

Now I would like to replace the text "Foo" at runtime using a binding, but obviously I can't place a {..} binding in place of Foo here. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Content="{Binding Text} ? (just a guess)

Comment: It would normally be 'Content="{Binding Text}', and that is a good guess, but this control is different. Quite unexpected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across this,

```
<Label>
    <Underline Foreground="Blue">
        <Underline.Inlines>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>
        </Underline.Inlines>
    </Underline>
</Label>
```

And in fact you can reduce that to this,

```
<Label>
    <Underline Foreground="Blue">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>
    </Underline>
</Label>
```

Or you can do it like this,

```
<Label Name="label">
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock" TextDecorations="Underline" Text="Test"/>
</Label>
```

So back to your underline with the text 'Foo' you were defining an inline.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.underline.aspx

It says this,

An inline-level flow content element which causes content to render with an underlined text decoration.

So it is a group of inlines, and takes the format of this,

```
<Underline>
  Inlines
</Underline>
```